# keep track of multiple generated class instances to clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, instance, cleartimeout

It may very well be my lack of vocabulary that I didn't find an awnser to my current problem.

I have a simple time count down class:

```
class Timecounter {
    constructor(..) {
        ...
    }
    count() {
        ....
        this.cnt = setTimeout(() => this.count(), 1000);
    }
    start() {
        this.count();
    }
    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.cnt);
    }
}
```

From that I manually create an instance, start & stop, for more instances just change the tmr 'name':

```
function startButton(event, elem_id) {
    tmr = new Timecounter(Date.now(), 10000, elem_id);
    tmr.start();
}

function stopButton() {
    tmr.stop();
    tmr = null;
}
```

But now, I'd like to have the back end generate dozens of the instances like above in a page so I can manually start them. How do I keep track of each instance and match them with the right buttons so I can stop each one separately? Dozens of independent sets of timer and two buttons?

Comment: Just put them in an array and give everyone an index that you can reference from the button?

Comment: @Bergi, you mean like:
timerarray['tmr1']=new Timecounter(Date.now(), 10000, "1");
timerarray['tmr2']=new Timecounter(Date.now(), 10000, "2");
etc.
and then startButton(event, timer_id, ....)

Comment: Yes, like that, though the array indices should be integers and the DOM ids should be alphanumeric - `timerarray[0] = new TimeCounter(Date.now(), 10000, "tmr"+0)` or so

Comment: thanks @Bergi, reading up arrays now